# C# linq totalization

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get a totalization by enum values. See this example:

In this source:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    enum fruits { Orange, Grape, Papaya }

    class item
    {
        public fruits fruit;
        public string foo;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            item[] list = new item[]
            {
                new item() { fruit = fruits.Orange, foo = "afc" },
                new item() { fruit = fruits.Orange, foo = "dsf" },
                new item() { fruit = fruits.Orange, foo = "gsi" },
                new item() { fruit = fruits.Orange, foo = "jskl" },
                new item() { fruit = fruits.Grape, foo = "mno" },
                new item() { fruit = fruits.Grape, foo = "pqu" },
                new item() { fruit = fruits.Grape, foo = "tvs" },
            };

            var vTotals = from... //Here


        }
    }
}
```

I would like to vTotals be
of type

```
Dictionary<fruits, int>
```

with the values

```
{
    { fruits.Orange, 4 }
    { fruits.Grape, 3 }
    { fruits.Papaya, 0 }
}
```

How I can do it with Linq?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do here is logically a group join.  You want to join this table with a sequence representing each of the fruits, and then count the size of those groups.

```
var totals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(fruits)).OfType<fruits>()
    .GroupJoin(list,
        fruit => fruit,
        item => item.fruit,
        (fruit, group) => new { Key = fruit, Value = group.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use group join of all fruit types with items:

```
var vTotals = from fruits f in Enum.GetValues(typeof(fruits))
              join i in list on f equals i.fruit into g
              select new {
                 Fruit = f,
                 Count = g.Count()
              };
```

Result:

```
[
  { Fruit: "Orange", Count: 4 },
  { Fruit: "Grape", Count: 3  },
  { Fruit: "Papaya", Count: 0 }
]
```

Comment: I don't think that this will include papayas

Comment: @Selman22 It will.  A `GroupJoin` will always have exactly as many entries as there are items in the first collection.

Comment: @Servy so this will translated into `GroupJoin` or `Join` ? how is this perform a left outer join?

Comment: @Selman22 It will be translated into a group join.  This code will translate exactly into the code shown in my answer (with the exception that Sergey omitted the `ToDictionary` call).  A group join creates a group of "matching" items from the second sequences for each item in the first.  That group can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. It may not be considered as pretty as doing it all in one query, but it is (IMO) clear: (first part of the code thanks to [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley), who since deleted his answer)

```
var vTotals = list.GroupBy(i => i.fruit)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
foreach (var fruit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(fruits)).Cast<fruits>()
                          .Where(x => !vTotals.ContainsKey(x)))
{
    vTotals.Add(fruit, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var total = from e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(fruits)).OfType<fruits>()
                select new
                {
                    Fruit = e,
                    Count = list.Where(f => f.fruit == e).Count()
                };
```

Comment: This quite a bit less efficient than the two top answers, in that you're doing a linear search of the second collection for each item in the first.

Answer (score 0):

From @Servy's answer, if you want to unit test it, using MSTest.

```
[TestClass]
public class DummyTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void GroupCountByFruitType() {
        // arrange
        var expected = new Dictionary<Fruits, int>() { 
            { Fruits.Grape, 3 }
            , { Fruits.Orange, 4 }
            , { Fruits.Papaya, 0 } 
        };

        Item[] list = new Item[] {
            new Item() { Fruit = Fruits.Orange, Foo = "afc" },
            new Item() { Fruit = Fruits.Orange, Foo = "dsf" },
            new Item() { Fruit = Fruits.Orange, Foo = "gsi" },
            new Item() { Fruit = Fruits.Orange, Foo = "jskl" },
            new Item() { Fruit = Fruits.Grape, Foo = "mno" },
            new Item() { Fruit = Fruits.Grape, Foo = "pqu" },
            new Item() { Fruit = Fruits.Grape, Foo = "tvs" }
        };

        // act
        var actual = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruits)).OfType<Fruits>()
            .GroupJoin(list
                , fruit => fruit
                , item => item.Fruit
                , (fruit, group) => new { Key = fruit, Value = group.Count() })
            .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);            

        // assert
        actual.ToList()
            .ForEach(item => Assert.AreEqual(expected[item.Key], item.Value));
    }

    private class Item {
        public Fruits Fruit { get; set; }
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    private enum Fruits {
        Grape,
        Orange,
        Papaya
    }
}
```

Comment: If the actual implementation was `var actual = new Dictionary<fruits, int>();` it'd past your test.  I also don't really see how posting a single trivial test case of an existing answer is really an answer to the question.

Comment: @Servy: Yes it does. I simply have used capitals because of the .NET conventions. The OP might as well prefer to use lowercases. Just to let you know, I +1 your answer, since I have never used grouping this way with Linq. I saw something new somehow. =)

Answer (score -1):

This should do it

```
 var vTotals = list.GroupBy(item => item.fruit)
            .Select(item => Tuple.Create(item.Key, item.Count()))
            .ToDictionary(key => key.Item1, value => value.Item2);
```

Here we simply group on the fruit name with their count and later turn it into a dictionary

Comment: this will not include papayas.